# php5 OOP - object type restriction doesn't work

Tags: php, oop

I'm learning OOP, and got a little problem here with not understanding the code.

Here it is.

```
class ShopProduct {

    private $title;
    private $producerMainName;
    private $producerFirstName;
    protected $price;
    private $discount = 0;


    function __construct( $name, $firstName, $mainName, $price) {
        $this->title = $name;
        $this->producerFirstName = $firstName;
        $this->producerMainName = $mainName;
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    public function getProducer() {
        return "{$this->producerMainName} "."{$this->producerFirstName} \n ";
    }

    public function setDiscount($num){
        $this->discount = $num;
    }

    public function getDiscount() {
        return $this->discount;
    }

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function getPrice() {
        return ($this->price - $this->discount);
    }

    public function getSummaryLine() {
        $base = "{$this->title} ( {$this->producerMainName}, ";
        $base .= "{$this->producerFirstName} )";
        return $base;
    }
}

class CDProduct extends ShopProduct {
    private $playLength = 0;

    public function __construct($title, $firstName, $mainName, $price, $playLength) {
        parent::__construct($title, $firstName, $mainName, $price);
        $this->playLength = $playLength;
    }

    public function getPlayLength() {
        return $this->playLength;
    }

    public function getSummaryLine() {
        $base = parent::getSummaryLine();
        $base .= ": {$this->playLength()} minutes";
        return $base;
    }

}
class BookProduct extends ShopProduct {

    private $numPages = 0;

    public function __construct($title, $firstName, $mainName, $price, $numPages) {
        parent::__construct($title, $firstName, $mainName, $price);
        $this->numPages = $numPages;
    }


    public function getNumberOfPages() {
        return $this->numPages;
    }

    public function getSummaryLine() {
        $base = parent::getSummaryLine();
        $base .= ": {$this->numPages()} pages";
        return $base;
    }
}
class ShopProductWriter {

    private $products = array();
    public function addProduct($shopProduct){
        if(! ($shopProduct instanceof ShopProduct) ){
        die('object error');
        }
        $this->products[] = $shopProduct;
    }
    public function write($shopProduct) {   
        foreach($this->products as $shopProducts){
            $str = "{$shopProduct->getTitle()}: "."{$shopProduct->getProducer()}"." {$shopProduct->getPrice()}$ \n";
        }
        print $str;
    }
}
$product = new CDProduct('Song is the rythm','Zyxel','Beatz',50, 60.33);
$write = new ShopProductWriter();
$write->addProduct($product);
$write->write($product);
```

The problem is here

```
class ShopProductWriter {

        private $products = array();
        public function addProduct($shopProduct){
            if(! ($shopProduct instanceof ShopProduct) ){
            die('object error');
            }
            $this->products[] = $shopProduct;
        }
        public function write($shopProduct) {   
            foreach($this->products as $shopProducts){
                $str = "{$shopProduct->getTitle()}: "."{$shopProduct->getProducer()}"." {$shopProduct->getPrice()}$ \n";
            }
            print $str;
        }
    }
```

As you see there is condition - if the object is not ShopProduct type - goes error.
But as you see i'm creating CDProduct object.

```
$product = new CDProduct('Song is the rythm','Zyxel','Beatz',50, 60.33);
$write = new ShopProductWriter();
$write->addProduct($product);
$write->write($product);
```

It should show error. Anybody can say me what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects of CDProduct are also of type ShopProduct.  In the class definition:

```
class CDProduct extends ShopProduct {
```

So it is an object of both types.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

If an object extends a parent or implements an interface, it can be considered of that type also.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php

Comment: I see, so when it extends from some class, its getting type from parent?

Comment: Bu Aksam, when u extends some class, that class become the 2 types. So, CDProduct instanceof CdProduct and ShopProduct, and Shopproduct instanceof ShopProduct just.

Comment: As an aside, this a feature of Inheritance, and in general you can have an inheritance chain that can be any number of classes long. e.g. you can have a class that extends Parent1, which in turn extends Parent2 and so on.  The ultimate base class can be considered an object of the same type all the way up the chain.

Answer (score 0):

You got already feedback about why a `CDProduct` is a `ShopProduct`, so I just add another hint on some code you've written where PHP has already support for:

```
    public function addProduct($shopProduct){
        if(! ($shopProduct instanceof ShopProduct) ){
        die('object error');
        }
        $this->products[] = $shopProduct;
    }
```

Instead of doing the check on your own, you can just make use of [*Type Hinting*](http://php.net/language.oop5.typehinting) to reduce your code *and* make it more expressive:

```
    public function addProduct(ShopProduct $shopProduct) {
        $this->products[] = $shopProduct;
    }
```

I hope this helps as you wrote you're currently learning about OOP.